# detect events in Gitlab repo

Tags: node.js, github, events, gitlab, webhooks

I need something similar to Github Webhooks in Gitlab.
https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events

I have read gitlab documentation but there user needs to add webhook himself on individual repository.

I have created a Gitlab App for authenticating gitlab users, after authenticating I am getting access_token and refresh_token and with this I am able to get user's private repositories, now what I want is that whenever user pushes new code in any of his repo, I want to be notified with the event and payload in my nodejs application.

Below is the settings of my Gitlab App.

[image]